# Limits for conditional variance of $X$ given $Y$?

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, variance

> $$f(x,y)= 8xy \space\space\space\space\space\space\text { for } 0 \lt x \lt y \lt 1$$

What will be limits for integration in the formula for conditional variance of $X$ given $Y$?

Will it be from **$x$ to $1$** or from **$0$ to $y$**?

Edit: I am getting the answer 0 upon inserting the limits 0 to y. Could it be correct?

Comment: You just asked almost the exact same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388456/moment-generating-function-of-y