# Moment Generating Function of Y

Tags: statistics, density-function, moment-generating-functions, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

f(x,y)=8xy       for 0

What will be the MGF of Y?

Do I need to insert the marginal density function for Y in the formula for MGF?

Also, what will be the limits? Will it be from x to 1 or from 0 to 1?

Comment: Your joint density needs more specification. It is not clear where it is defined, as written.

Answer (score 1):

From the question "Also, what will be the limits? Will it be from x to 1 or from 0 to 1?" I will assume that the proper joint density is
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 8xy\cdot\mathsf 1_{0<x<y<1}.
$$

To find the moment-generating function of $Y$, we first need to determine its marginal distribution. To do this, we integrate over all possible values of $X$:

$$
f_Y(y) = \int_0^y8xy\ \mathsf dx = 4y^3\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(y).
$$

Next we compute the expectation
$$
\mathbb E[e^{tY}] = \int_0^1 e^{ty} 4y^3\ \mathsf dy = \frac{4 e^t (t ((t-3) t+6)-6)+24}{t^4}
$$
(this requires some repeated integration by parts, which I have omitted for brevity.